# Xamarin Forms: Image height request ignored inside frame inside relative layout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following code:

```
<ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <StackLayout Spacing="0" Padding="15,0">
                    <Frame HasShadow="false" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="0">
                        <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Olive" Padding="0" VerticalOptions="End">
                            <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Purple" Padding="0" HasShadow="false">
                                <Image HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50" Source="assets/avatar-man.png"></Image>
                            </Frame>
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Teal" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=100}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-100}" />
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="false" Padding="0" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant, Constant=100}" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-100}">
                                <Label>Hello</Label>
                            </Frame>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

However, for some reason the Image height request gets ignored and instead of showing a 50x50 unit square, it fills the entire screen like this:

[image: Issue Image]

Does anyone know why this gets ignored and how to fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the same issue, I ended up wrapping a StackLayout around my image like this:

```
<StackLayout>
  <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}" WidthRequest="50" HeightRequest="50"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I'm using a <ContentView> instead of a <StackLayout> as it gives me a better flexibility to center the inner contents vertically.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just set a `Margin` on the Image, like so:

```
<Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Purple" Padding="0" HasShadow="false">
    <Image Margin="25" VerticalOptions="Center" Source="assets/avatar-man.png"></Image>
</Frame>
```

Just take the size (height or width) of the `Frame`, subtract the size of the `Image`, and divide by 2. This will set the image size to 50.

Easy way to do it if the size of the frame won't change.